# Rain and its velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Do rain fall with constant velocity? Why this phenomena occur although presence of gravity acceleration
And how to obtain this force

Comment: http://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2013/09/10/how-fast-do-raindrops-fall/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The droplets are accelerated by gravity and also experience a drag force proportional to their speed. At their maximal speed both forces are equal and opposite in direction.

For more detail look here
https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2007/EvanKaplan.shtml

or here https://www.wired.com/2011/08/how-fast-is-falling-rain/